# Can't connect to Microsoft SQL Server (VM) through ODBC

Tags: sql-server, oracle, server, virtual-machine

I'm having an issue with the connection with the Microsoft SQL Server from VM. As I started on creating a new data source to the SQL server, the server does not recognize my SQL server and even though I did type in the server name and server IP address. Somehow I got an error that illustrates either my server does not exist or access denied.

I already had set up DCP port along with the SQL configuration, VM setting, still, I can't connect to the virtual SQL server on Oracle VM virtual box
By the way, the VM is connected to the domain

Here are several screenshots of my configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check windows background services and check if sql server agent service is running?

Comment: @Mr.AF Yes,the sql serve agent service is running properly but although i noticed that the SQLPBDMS stopped running. Does it always like that?

Comment: i faced your problem before and i was able to fix it by re-starting sql server services. for assure , try to start all of the services and try again.

Comment: I'm confused about "who's on first".  You mention a VM under OracleVirtualBox (I assume that is why you tagged this 'oracle', since there is no oracle db involved).  What OS is the vm running?  Is the SQL Srver on the VM? The host? Some other machine?  Where is the ODBC? The host? Some other machine? If you have correctd the IPv4 setting and still have an issue, I suspect it is in your network settings for the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Network Configuration manager for TCP/IP Properties on the *IP Address* tab for ipv4 set *Enabled* property to `Yes`. It's **No** in your provided screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I did test that and it recognized my server but however, it still failed to connect to the SQL. However, whenever I'm switching to the bridged adapter, my internet connection is gone until I switch back to NAT

Comment: @Phạm Quốc Minh Đăng what account are you trying to use? Are you sure it has permissions to the SQL server? You may need to add a new log in.

Comment: @vvv4d i do have TCPIP enable(you can check the above image along with port being set to 1433) . However, I decided to recreate the SQL user authentication to see if it accessible or not since i haven't assign role for the account

Comment: When you are setting up the ODBC connection are you using the VM name or IP address for the server?

Comment: @vvv4d I use VM name to connect to ODBC

Comment: @Phạm Quốc Minh Đăng can you try going by IP address and see if that works?

Comment: I see the issue now in the ipv4 setting changed Enabled to true. It's false currently.